# How to get the IndexOf() blank space in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my Linq query

```
var test = from k in db.CityTable
           where k.Name.Substring(0,1)== test1 && k.Name.Substring(4,1) == test2
           select k.CityName;
```

k.Name will have values as shown below in the Database Table

**Example:** New York or New Jersey
Here test1 and test 2 are string variables,which contains single characters like N or Y or J.
Now i want to compare the First Alphabet of k.Name with test1.

And compare test2 with the First Alphabet of the second word in k.Name.

Suppose New York is the value in Database column.

**test1=N**

**test2=Y**

**k.Name=New York**

Now it should compare N with first Alphabet of New and Y with the first Alphabet of York.
To achieve this i will have to get the first character after Space.

This is what i have tried,

```
test = from k in db.CityTable
where k.CityName.Substring(0,1)== test1 && k.CityName.Substring(k.CityName.IndexOf(' '),1) == test2                                               
select k.CityName;
```

but on this query i gets the exception

> base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Char)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."}

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you try it with `IndexOf(" ")`?Also you could try to take the data in `CityTable` to an in-memory list and then try this query on it.

Comment: @RoboLover my test1 and test2 will only have the abbrevations of the City in the Database.
And yes i have tried IndexOf()

Comment: You tried `IndexOf` with a `char` paramater, I am suggesting you to call it with a `string` parameter, please check my answer for the msdn `IndexOf` example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider trying `IndexOf(" ")`, this could also be nicer `IndexOf(string.Empty)`, check [String.IndexOf(substring)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737939#strindof).

```
where k.CityName.Substring(0,1)== test1 && k.CityName.Substring(k.CityName.IndexOf(" "),1) == test2
```